# Is there any enhanced gdb console for Eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gdb

Currently the gdb console of Eclipse just connects the stdin/stdout between the java gui and the underlying gdb process, hence many gdb shell features are missing, e.g. tab-autocomplete, command history etc.

I want to know if there is an enhanced console for fast gdb interacting. I really like the frequently used gdb commands like "print" and "call" etc. IMHO, "print" command is superiors sometimes than Eclipse "Expression watcher" because it only execute once and the later will be evaluated any time and be crash-prone.

If you think there is no need to use gdb console, then what's you best-practise in terms of gdb UI to eclipse UI transfer.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any gdb-specific plugin, beside the initial gdb integration [initiated with Eclipse3.4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DSDP/DD/GDB).

And the [current list of gdb bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=cdt-debug-cdi-gdb) doesn't include your missing features.

Comment: It's not bug anyway, I can feel that the current gdb console window is implemented in a simple way, maybe need to be improved...

Comment: @solotim: I agree. Note that you can find RFE (Request for Enhancement) in their bug tracking system too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing c/++, why not just find the eclipse-generated elf and use gdb via the shell?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. I transferred from gdb/ddd to Eclipse simply because I like some Eclipse features, such as the debug interface and utilities. It will be great if the platform can bring together the best things from two worlds.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write the Eclipse plugin that does what you want ;)

Comment: @solotim: GDB in console is the best, or even scripted. Go script your Eclipse to automatically run a GDB scenario...